# A fast way to read and store some values inside a big log file with Perl

Tags: perl, search, logging

Sorry for asking so many times questions about reading lines and other thingies. I happen to be dealing with a huge (500,000 lines) file like this:

```
2013-05-27T19:01:23 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:29 [INFO] item_id:2, pause at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:3, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:3, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:3, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
```

What I need to do is, given the file location as input, make a script which output should resemble something like this:

```
$output = [ {item_id => 1, counter => 2 }, { item_id......
```

That is, each item_id should be paired with the number of starts it has inside an array ref. Notice that I can't use a "while" to read the file more than once, since its way too big. Also, I do not know a priori how many items there are.

The method I wrote using tips from Stackoverflow members is as follows:

```
sub count_start{
open LOGFILE, $file_location;
my $max;
my $i;
my $counter = 0;
my $found = 0;
my $data;

while (<LOGFILE>) {
  next unless /item_id:(\d+)/;
  $found = $1 if $found < $1;

  for ($i =1, $i<=$found, $i++){
   if ($file_location =~ /\bitem_id:$i, start\b/ig){
   $counter++;
   }
  $output = [ $i => $counter ];
  } 
}
close LOGFILE;
return $output;
}
1;
```

But everything went really wrong :(. I get a lot of nasty warnings and nothing remotely similar to what I was asked for. Any ideas or suggestions?

Forgive this perl newbie for his awful code.

Comment: If you want to store the data, using perl code as the format is not the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a hash to do the counting, then transform it to an array of hashes afterwards. However, it looks like you are using perl code to store your data, which is not the best idea. There are better formats, such as [`JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON), or even [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV).

That aside, the [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper) module can be used for this purpose.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %output;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/ item_id:(\d+), start at /) {
        $output{$1}++;
    }
}

my @data = map { { item_id => $_, counter => $output{$_} } } keys %output;
print Dumper \@data;


__DATA__
2013-05-27T19:01:23 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:29 [INFO] item_id:2, pause at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:3, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:3, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:3, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'counter' => 5,
            'item_id' => '1'
          },
          {
            'counter' => 3,
            'item_id' => '3'
          },
          {
            'counter' => 5,
            'item_id' => '5'
          }
        ];
```

Note that the output is unsorted, due to the fact that hashes are not sorted. If you want it sorted, you can apply the `sort` function to the keys.

Also note that this version takes into account that you said to count the "starts", which with this input does not include line #2 that says `item_id:2, pause at`.

Comment: TLP thanks for the awesome solution I like the Data::Dumper module usage here. And yes I am using perl code to store the data. Is it too bad? I was thinking of writing a code that moves the perl hash to a txt file, flat file or even a DB later.

Comment: The problem is that when reading data stored in perl code, it requires evaluation, so you need to do something like `my $data = do 'input.txt';`, which will execute arbitrary code in that file. Using a well tested and documented format is generally speaking a better idea, and also portable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put hash like associations in a list. For that you need a hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %output;
my $filename = shift @ARGV;
open my $file, "<", $filename or die("$!: $filename");
while (<$file>) {
    if (/item_id:(\d+)\s*,\s*start/) {
        $output{$1}++;
    }
}
close $file;
for my $item(keys %output) {
    print "$item -> $output{$item}\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
1 -> 5
3 -> 3
5 -> 4
```

You can replace the while loop with this:

```
/item_id:(\d+)\s*,\s*start/ and $output{$1}++ while <$file>;
```

but it isn't really readable.

Comment: thanks a lot perreal! awesome. yes the one liner takes some time to grasp